# Change the value of many Divs on select of drop-down

Tags: jquery, json

I have a jquery drop-down. On select of drop-down (i.e either first, second, third or fourth drop-down), we are able to achieve the value for first div.

I am looking to achieve the same concept for fetching values in the second and third div from json for the field **sales and transaction**

here is the fiddle on how far I have worked

```
demo: `http://jsfiddle.net/binoymat/d9f8t9vj/8/`
```

> Note:
>   When first drop-down is selected, we show combined values for that particular id, second drop-down selection, we show values only of that particular site.. vice versa with third and fourth values.. it has been achieved with the first div.. looking for solution for the second and third div

Comment: Why don't you add a value for 'All' in each of your dropdown? From UX perspective, it took me some time to understand how the values are calculated. Initially I expected the value 30 was for Main Entrance, Singapore, Asia at 11 Oct 2015 since the dropdown filter selected was:
ASIA | Singapore | Main Entrance | 11 Oct 2015

Better for user experience and simpler to implement too :)

Comment: thanks for the input Ken.. Will add that and make sure there is value for All to avoid further confusions

Comment: Any suggestions on how to achieve the values inside the second and third div???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have add two `span` for Sales and Transaction and link your fields.

Please try:

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ooc9", function (data) {
    //code inside
    var items = data;
    var checkIds = [];
    $.each(items, function (k, v) {
        if ($.inArray(v.id, checkIds) == -1) {
            $("#category").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.chains + '</option>');
            checkIds.push(v.id);
        }
    });

    $("#category").on('change', function () {
        var dept_number = parseInt($(this).val());
        var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
        var tochange = false;
        var total = 0;
        var totalSales= 0;
        var totalTrans= 0;
        $.each(items, function (k, v) {
            if (v.id == dept_number) {
                if (tochange == true) {
                    $("#category1").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-tran="' + v.transaction + '" data-sales="' + v.sales + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.site + '</option>');
                    $("#category2").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-tran="' + v.transaction + '" data-sales="' + v.sales + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.zone + '</option>');
                    $("#category3").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-tran="' + v.transaction + '" data-sales="' + v.sales + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.date + '</option>');
                } else {
                    $("#category1").html('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-tran="' + v.transaction + '" data-sales="' + v.sales + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.site + '</option>');
                    $("#category2").html('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-tran="' + v.transaction + '" data-sales="' + v.sales + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.zone + '</option>');
                    $("#category3").html('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-tran="' + v.transaction + '" data-sales="' + v.sales + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.date + '</option>');
                    tochange = true;
                }
                total += v.visitors;
                totalSales += v.sales;
                totalTrans += v.transaction;
            }
        });
        $('#dept-input').val(dept_number);
        $('#price-input').val(total);
        $("#totalVisitors").text(total);
        $("#totalSales").text(totalSales);
        $("#totalTransaction").text(totalTrans);
    }).change();

    $("select[id^='category']:not(#category)").on('change', function () {
        var dept_number = parseInt($(this).val());
        var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
        var sales = $(this).find(':selected').data('sales');
        var transaction = $(this).find(':selected').data('tran');
        $('#dept-input').val(dept_number);
        $('#price-input').val(price);
       $("#totalVisitors").text(price);
        $("#totalSales").text(sales);
        $("#totalTransaction").text(transaction);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="category"></select>
<select id="category1"></select>
<select id="category2"></select>
<select id="category3"></select>
<br>
<br>
<div class="total"  style="width: 300px;height: 100px;background-color: #006a72;color: white;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; line-height: 45px;">TOTAL VISITORS FOR THE DAY
    <br>
        <span id="totalVisitors" ></span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="total" style="width: 300px;height: 100px;background-color: orange;color: white;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; line-height: 45px;">Sales
    <br>
        <span id="totalSales" ></span>
</div>
    <br>
    <div class="total" style="width: 300px;height: 100px;background-color: red;color: white;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; line-height: 45px;">Transaction
    <br>
        <span id="totalTransaction" ></span>
</div>
<label>Chain id:</label>
<input type="text" id="dept-input"></input>
<br>
<br>
<label>Visitors:</label>
<input type="text" id="price-input"></input>
```